# How to create a bigger size image in Java2D

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory, java-2d

What is the maximum size of an image can be created using Java 2D?

I am using Windows 7 Pro 64 bit OS and JDK 1.6.0_33, 64 bit version. I can able to create a BufferedImage up to 5 MB of size. Beyond that I am getting OutOfMemoryError.

Please guide me how to create a bigger size image using Java 2D or JAI.

Here is my attempt.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;    
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;     
import java.io.File;    
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;    

public class CreateBiggerImage
{
private String fileName = "images/107.gif";
private String outputFileName = "images/107-Output.gif";

public CreateBiggerImage()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage image = readImage(fileName);
        ImageIO.write(createImage(image, 9050, 9050), "GIF", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), outputFileName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private BufferedImage readImage(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), fileName));
    return image;
}

private BufferedImage createImage(BufferedImage image, int outputWidth, int outputHeight) throws Exception
{
    int actualImageWidth = image.getWidth();
    int actualImageHeight = image.getHeight();

    BufferedImage imageOutput = new BufferedImage(outputWidth, outputHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = imageOutput.createGraphics();
    for (int width = 0; width < outputWidth; width += actualImageWidth)
    {
        for (int height = 0; height < outputHeight; height += actualImageHeight)
        {
            g2d.drawImage(image, width, height, null);
        }
    }
    g2d.dispose();

    return imageOutput;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new CreateBiggerImage();
}
}
```

Comment: How much memory are you giving your Java program?

Comment: Hi Kayaman, I have tried the following, java -jar MaxMemoryTest.jar as well as java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m MaxMemoryTest.jar

Comment: Your image of size 9050 x 9050 is using 4 bytes per pixel (for TYPE_INT_RGB). This results in 327610000 bytes, or > 312 MB in memory.  Are you sure about the 5 MB limit? It should be doable with -Xmx1024m, unless of course also the input image is huge. Also remember that the JVM needs a block of *contiguous free space* to create the int array for your image on the heap. So having 1024 MB of heap is no guarantee (but it *should* work).

Answer (score 2):

The "maximum size" of image you can create with Java 2D depends on a lot of things... So I'll make a few assumptions here (correct me if I'm wrong):

- By "size", you mean dimensions (width x height), not memory consumption
- By "image", you mean `BufferedImage`

With these assumptions, the theoretical limit is given by `(width * height * bits per pixel / bits in transfer type) == Integer.MAX_VALUE` (in other words, the largest array you can create). As an example, for `TYPE_INT_RGB` or `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, you'll use 32 bits per pixel, and the the transfer type is also 32 bit. For `TYPE_3BYTE_RGB` you'll use 24 bits per pixel, but the transfer type is only 8 bit, so the maximum size is actually smaller.

It's possible that you could theoretically create even larger tiled `RenderedImage`s. Or use custom `Raster`s with multiple bands (multiple arrays).

In any case, your limiting factor will be available contiguous memory.

To overcome this, I've created a [DataBuffer implementation that uses a memory mapped file](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedFileBuffer.java) to store image data outside the JVM heap. It's entirely experimental, but I've successfully created `BufferedImage`s where `width * height ~= Integer.MAX_VALUE / 4`. Performance is not great, but may be acceptable for certain applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harald. I haven't worked with rasters and RenderedImage and all I know is BufferedImage. I have to update myself on this.